# C# file path with web browser control not working as string variable

Tags: c#, string, webbrowser-control

I have a web browser control in my win form and I want to use the navigate method to open a local pdf file. If I hard code the url string as a string literal and pass that to navigate as a new Uri it works just fine:

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
...
string url = @"file:///C:\folder\01 - folder\my pdf file.pdf"
wb.Navigate(new Uri(url));
wb.Show();
```

As you can see, my path has spaces and it seems when I try to load the same string as a variable, (so not a string literal) the web browser doesn't know what to do. I have "shaped" my string using different methods to make it look identical to the above but since I cannot write it as a string literal it does not work. I guess the other option is to escape all backslashes but I think there is a problem with the spaces then. Can anyone give a concrete example of how to make this work by passing a string variable.

Comment: Code you provided works? If yes, what code does not work? Provide it too.

Comment: How does `url` look like if you use it as "variable"?

Comment: Actually, I have tried now, and it seems "working" - the file download dialog appears. What does your issue look like?

Comment: the value from the debugger says this: "file:///\"E:\\Root\\01 - Academic\\01 - Engineering\\Computer\\01 - Software and Web Development\\Architecture\\MyFile.pdf\"" and writing to the console gives file:///"E:\Root\01 - Academic\01 - Engineering\Computer\01 - Software and Web Development\Architecture\MyFile.pdf"

Comment: The error I get is a pop up box from the web browser saying it cannot find the file however I know the path works as a literal as I have tested it successfully

Comment: Note what you have in your question (`C:`) and what you now write in the comment (`\"E:`). Please double sure you posted the same code you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I actually managed to figure it out but I don't fully understand WHY it works. I suspect that by making the first string in the url a literal it "forces" the entire string to be treated as such (And literals work fine in the Uri method). Anyways, hopefully this helps out someone who might be stuck on the same thing.

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();

string path = yourPath; // I have something like "C:\Folder 1\Folder 2"
string fileName = yourFileName; // "something.pdf"

string url = @"file:///" + path + fileName;

wb.Navigate(new Uri(url));
wb.Show();
```

Note: I got path by passing a openFileDialog resulting fileName to a private method that parses out the path and did the same for the fileName.